# What are my options for a long-term visa? (Between SA & European citizen)

Tags: visa, citizenship, eu-citizens, eu-spouses, dual-citizenship

I wanted to find out what are some of the options we can consider for applying for a long-term visa.

I am a South African citizen and my partner is European. We would like to find out if there are any options for us to possibly look into applying for a long-term visa.

Comment: Do you want a long-term visa for any particular place?

Comment: He is from Germany and I am from SA. So I was trying to find out who will stand a better chance of getting their Visa approved between us.

Comment: Who has a better chance of getting the visa approved depends entirely on *which country you're applying to,* which you have not yet said.  Do you want to move to Ireland?  The US?  Ethiopia?  Laos?

Comment: You could always go to Svalbard, where neither of you needs a visa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvious option is to live in an EU country that is not your partner's country of citizenship, as a family member of an eea national exercising their treaty rights.

But you should add some more details or read other answers on this site because the question as it stands is rather broad.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I was wondering if me being South African and my partner European, who stands a better chance for applying for a long-term visa. Not the tourist visa which is 90 days for Europeans

Comment: @Jay see phoog's comment. Do I take it you don't mind where you live as long as you are together? By default the simplest option is to go to Europe, maybe even to your partner's country, depending on their rules regarding EU treaty rights. But it might be that your partner is also well qualified to emigrate to SA?

Comment: Thanks so much. It will ideal if he comes to this side because he is an entrepreneur and I am an employee with a permanent job this side that is office-bound. We will take your advice and ask both our embassies the requirements.